# NSMutableData cannot be read

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledata

```
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[self addFormData:@"username" withString:@"tom"]];

 NSLog(@"-----the body is %@----", body);
```

But the NSLog shows <0d345621 67543687 d123ab023 ........etc>

I thought it should shows "username"="tom"   all those hex stuffs i mean no one will able to understand it.

Comment: It's "data" -- bytes. You need to get it into an NSString to print the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to a string for use/display, example:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
```

Do consider the encoding that is correct for this data--if it is a character string at all.

Comment: May I recommend `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead? Of course it's irrelevant in this case, but UTF8 should always be preferred over ASCII.

Comment: @Tom, Sure, `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is what I usually use and have changed my answer! But I had to make a choice and thought  `NSASCIIStringEncoding` might be best here.